# Unable to deploy/update google cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project with 29 functions 2 with python and 27 with nodejs.

Modified 2 of them and now I can't deploy properly. I get an error log that send me to the logviewer and one of the errors is:

> ERROR: build step 3
> "us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/nodejs10/builder:nodejs10_20201201_20_RC00"
> failed: step exited with non-zero status: 46

The functions keep on working, but I can't update/deploy properly. When I try to deploy them individually I get that error for both functions, but when I try to deploy ALL the functions I only get the error with those 2 functions the rest of the functions, that don't have any modification have no problem redeploying.

I checked the source code in the Cloud console and they have a warning icon saying that:

> Function is active, but last deployment failed

The source code in the Cloud console is the same as the one I'm trying to deploy but the functions has the same functionality that before when I made the changes, the functions still works but can't update.

These are javascript functions that I deployed using the Firebase Node Sdk.

Any help?

EDIT I:
I reverted the changes on one of the functions that's been there for over 2 years and still have the same issue, can't update/deploy, that function triggers on `storage.onFinalize()`.
The other function on `firestore.onCreate()`

EDIT II:
The newest function that I created is not in use, is part of a new feature in my android application, so I duplicated it, gave it different name and deployed without issues. In that case I could delete the original function without any issue as is not being used. But I can't do the same for the other function, the other function is constantly in use.

Comment: It would be highly relevant to tell us about what changed you made.  If you revert the changes do the errors go away?

Comment: If the Firebase CLI deployment is giving you an error message that's not actionable, then reach out to Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @AllanWind On of the functions is relatively new to the project, last proper deploy was the 8th version, since then I just added a `log` and tried to redeploy with no luck. I'll revert the other one that has been there for over 2 years to before I made the changes.